# TPL Asynchronous Static Method Call Thread Safety

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I need to make four calls to a WCF service asynchronously and thread safety with async stuff and static methods always cooks my brain.

These four async calls to the static method should be thread safe right?

```
    private void CheckStuff()
    {
        bool? res1, res2, res3, res4;

        // make 4 async calls to SomeServiceCall and wait for all
        Task[] tasks = new Task[]
                            {
                                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => res1 = SomeServiceCall("apple")),
                                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => res2 = SomeServiceCall("orange")),
                                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => res3 = SomeServiceCall("apple")),
                                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => res4 = SomeServiceCall("banana"))
                            };
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    private static bool? SomeServiceCall(string someParam)
    {
        bool? retVal = null;

        var client = new SomeWcfClient();

        retVal = client.CheckSomething(someParam);

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there's no shared state, so there should be no thread-safety issues. (EDIT: As noted in comments, that's assuming that it's okay to access *separate* `SomeWcfClient` instances from multiple threads concurrently. They would have to be poorly written for that to be a problem.)

You may find that the channel is limited to two connections to the same host/port at a time, but that's a separate matter and only affects the parallelism, not the thread safety.

As an aside, it's not at all clear why you'd want to declare the return variable before creating the client, and assign it a value which will never be used. Simpler code:

```
private static bool? SomeServiceCall(string someParam)
{
    var client = new SomeWcfClient();
    return client.CheckSomething(someParam);
}
```

Comment: There's no *explicit* shared state in the example. No telling what `SomeWcfClient` does.

Comment: @JimMischel: Well that's true - but if two separate instances can't be called from separate threads, then really all bets are off. If the code used a single instance of `SomeWpfClient` then that would be a different matter. I'd *expect* this code to be okay.

Comment: Also, since it's a WCF client, and *assuming* `SomeWcfClient` is a generated proxy, it should be wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer: I'll take your word for that. I'm not a WCF person :)

Comment: @Jon: I am going to have to go ahead and envy you now :)

Comment: `using` and other code optimizations are understood, just quick pseudo-code to get the point across.

@Jon SomeWcfClient would be a proxy to a WCF service and creating instances from separate threads is fine.  Though I am not sure about the limits on the connections for the channel...  How could I determine that if I don't own the service? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisHawkins: It's not a service issue, it's an HTTP connection pool issue. I suggest you just try it and watch what happens in Wireshark or via logging. There's an app.config setting you can specify to give per-host connection limits; I can't remember it offhand but I can look it up if necessary.